# Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HtmlInputEvent'

Tags: angular, file, events

I am trying to upload a file but I get that error, help me please to compile.

Angular-Error:

```
src/app/admin/producto/create-producto-dialog.html:38:47 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HtmlInputEvent'.
  Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
    Type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement & EventTarget'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement & EventTarget'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.

                         (change)="imgSelected($event)">
```

Code from component.ts

```
interface HtmlInputEvent extends Event{
  target : HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
} 

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public file :File;
  public imgSelect : String | ArrayBuffer;

  imgSelected(event: HtmlInputEvent){
    if(event.target.files  && event.target.files[0]){
        this.file = <File>event.target.files[0];

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => this.imgSelect = reader.result as String;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }
  }
}
```

Code from Html

```
<div class="text-center">
      <img [src]="imgSelect || '../../../../assets/img/default.jpg'" class="rounded-circle img-responsive mt-2" width="128" height="128">
      <div class="mt-2">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" (change)="imgSelected($event)" type="file" style="width: 100% !important;">
      </div>>
  </div>
```

I try with this 3 on tsconfig.json, but still don't work.

"strict": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
"strictFunctionTypes": false

I try with target : HTMLInputElement & EventTarget | null;

but when i put the null, my eevent.target on the if fail and say could be a null and i can't continue.

Thx

Comment: imgSelected(event: any) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    console.log(target);
  }

Comment: FYI there is a syntactic sugar for `event.target.files  && event.target.files[0]`. You can write it like this `event.target.files?.[0]`. This is a typescript feature called [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

Comment: With imgSelected(event: any) works, so i don't need the interface for nothing? I don't understand why this works

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach to typing a change event from an input is to type to a regular `Event` (which it is), and then typecast the `target`

```js
handleChange(event: Event) {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const file = target.files[0];
  // do something with the target or filees
}
```

Other event bindings produce different event types e.g. input is InputEvent, keyup is KeyboardEvent. The best way to see which to use is to `console.log` the event and see the objects class name